# Integrating $\int_{0}^{1} x^a (c-x)^b dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, beta-function

**Problem**

> How can I integrate $$\int_{0}^{1} x^a (c-x)^b dx $$ where $a,b,c$ are some constants.

**Solution Attempt**

For $c=1$, I have $\int_{0}^{1} x^a (1-x)^b dx = B(a+1,b+1)$, however, when $c \neq 1$ I am lost.

Comment: Google [binomial integral](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22binomial+integral%22).

Comment: @GuyFsone : Please take a look at the tag info for "[functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functions/info)" it is intended to be used for very basic properties of a mapping (domain, image, preimage, ...). The tag will becomes useless if all questions with a functions are tagged with "functions".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enforcing $x =ct$ gives $$\int_{0}^{1} x^a (c-x)^b dx= c^{a+b+1}\int_{0}^{c} t^a (1-t)^b dt =\color{red}{c^{a+b+1} \mathrm {B} (c;\,a,b) }$$

where $\mathrm {B} (c;\,a,b)$is the  [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), a generalization of the beta function.

Comment: I think you mean $x=ct$.

Comment: @Aforest corected aleady thanks

Comment: 1) shouldn't there be $c^{a+b+1}$ ?

Comment: @Snochacz of course see the answer it is jut a typo